# How to obtain one-way hash for given string in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, security

Is there a build in library in .NET that can compute secure one-way hash ? I mean a library that implements [SHA-2 cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) or something similar.

If is there is no SHA-2 implementation some weaker hash funcion would be sufficient.
If there are more options I prefer the most secure one.

Please provide a use example e.g. provide the code that returns one-way hash for string `mySampleString`.

---

EDIT: Please provide the example and the hash algorithm used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [SHA256Mananged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256managed.aspx) class to generate a hash of a string.  The [ComputeHash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a.aspx) documentation provides a complete example.

If you are targeting Vista+ only, you can use the faster [SHA256Cng](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256cng.aspx) class instead.  Just realize that it will throw on XP.

Comment: It is ment for asp.net aplication so the computation will take place on server. What option do I use for that ?

Comment: @drasto: If the server is 2008 or 2008R2 (not Server Core), use the Cng version.  If not, use Managed.

Comment: If you don't know the target you can test at startup if SHA256Cng works, then use a factory to return the SHA256Managed or SHA256Cng based on that result.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look in the [`System.Security.Cryptography`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx) namespace.
There you have a bunch of SHA-algorithms, MD5 etc.

Answer (score 0):

[HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash Method (Byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a.aspx)

Comment: The `HashAlgorithm` class is abstract, you need to pick a concrete implementation.

Comment: true that, just pick appropriate provider like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256cryptoserviceprovider_methods.aspx, that implements the ComputeHash(Byte[])